# Can I pass Variable of Object Datatype from Parent Package to Child Package on SSIS?

Tags: object, ssis, etl, parent-child

I have a Parent and Child Package. I am generating a full resultset through Execute SQL Task in the Parent package and saving it in a variable of Object Datatype.

However, when I pass this object's value from the parent package to the child package, I get this prompt:

[image: Error Prompt on Passing Variable Object Value from Parent Package to Child Package]

Is there a workaround for this?

I tried passing the value from Parent to Child Package, the same way it works for any variable. It's not working for Object datatype but working for rest. Also, the values are stored right in my object as tested through ForEach loop.